# does "are often too important to be neglected by wiser portion of mankind" means that the wiser portion don't disregard them?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

does "are often too important to be neglected by wiser portion of mankind" means that the wiser portion don't disregard them?

> Many sensible readers, we fear, will think we owe them an apology for
>   opening our columns to a controversy on such a subject as Spiritualism
>   and thus treating as an open or debatable question what should rather
>   be dismissed at once as either an imposture or a delusion. But even an
>   imposture may call for unmasking, and popular delusions howeverabsurd,
>   **are often too important to be neglected by the wiser portion of
>   mankind** . Is there, in reality, anything, as lawyers would say, to go
>   to a jury with? Well, on the one hand, we have abundance of alleged
>   experience which can hardly be called evidence, and a few depositions
>   of a more notable and impressive character. On the other hand, we have
>   many accounts of convicted impostors, and many authentic reports of
>   precisely such disappointments or discoveries as we should be led to
>   expect.

from http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holy compound sentence Batman.

Yes. Or at least they should not be disregarded.

> But even an imposture may call for unmasking, And popular delusions howeverabsurd, are often too important to be neglected by the wiser portion of mankind .

Could be

> ()Popular delusions () are () too important to be neglected by the wiser portion of mankind .

But note the sentence before that:

> opening our columns to a controversy on such a subject as Spiritualism and thus treating as an open or debatable question what should rather be dismissed at once as either an imposture or a delusion.

which, shortened, reads:

> (Starting a debate on) such a subject as Spiritualism and thus treating as an open () question what should () be dismissed at once as () a delusion.

So what the author is saying is: most people will dismiss this debate at once but these questions should not be disregarded.